# ¿Como restar dos SUM de tablas diferentes en sql server 2014?

Tags: sql-server-2014, powerbuilder

Estoy haciendo estas consultas en sql server 2014  en la cual hay cantidades con su id  y se sumara de acuerdo a la id.

Al ejecutar la primera consulta alias compra, si me devuelve la suma correcta ya que las cantidades son:

- id:2   cantidades  8 - 2  - 6       al sumar  16;
- id:3   cantidades    13     al sumar  13 ;
- id:6   cantidades  10 - 8   al sumar 18  ;

Al ejecutar la segunda consulta  alias venta también me devuelve la suma correcta:

- id: 2    cantidades    5  - 9       al sumar  14 ;
- id: 3    cantidades    8 - 7        al sumar  15 ;
- id  6    cantidades    8            al sumar  8 ;

Pero al unir la dos tablas y hacer la resta, no me suma correctamente como se ve en la ejecución de la tercera consulta , espero su ayuda , muchas gracias.

El código es el siguiente:

```
select pro.id_producto,sum(compra.cantidad) as compra 
from detalle_compra compra , producto pro
where  compra.id_producto=pro.id_producto
group by pro.id_producto

select pro.id_producto,sum(venta.cantidad) as venta 
from detall_venta venta , producto pro
where venta.id_producto=pro.id_producto
group by pro.id_producto

select pro.id_producto,sum(compra.cantidad) as compra,sum(venta.cantidad)as venta, (sum(compra.cantidad) - sum(venta.cantidad)) as stock
from  detall_venta venta,detalle_compra compra, producto pro
where   venta.id_producto=pro.id_producto and compra.id_producto=pro.id_producto
group by pro.id_producto
```

[image: sql]

Answer (score 0):

Puedes utilizar una tabla de expresión común correlativa, y calcular por un lado las compras, por otro las ventas y juntar ambas a la salida de las mismas.

```
with compras
     as (select pro.id_producto
              , sum(compra.cantidad) as compra
                from detalle_compra AS compra
                          inner join producto AS pro on compra.id_producto = pro.id_producto
                group by pro.id_producto),
     ventas
     as (select pro.id_producto
              , sum(venta.cantidad) as venta
                from detall_venta AS venta
                          inner join producto AS pro on pro.id_producto = venta.id_producto
                group by pro.id_producto)
     Select compras.id_producto
          , compras.compra
          , ventas.venta
          , compras.compra - ventas.venta as stock
            from compras
                      inner join ventas on compras.id_producto = ventas.id_producto;
```

Si observas la query, el conjunto compras, es tu Select de compras, pero cambiando el SQL-86 por SQL-92 estableciendo la union de las tablas en el ON y no en el Where

Lo mismo ocurre con la de ventas.

Luego en la salida de la tabla de expresión común juntamos ambas y obtenemos los resultados.

[image: Resultado]

Una mejora adicional, sería si tuvieses compras de un item, y no ventas o del revés, si tienes ventas y no compras, en vez de realizar un INNER JOIN de compras con ventas, lo puedes cambiar por un FULL JOIN

```
with compras
     as (select pro.id_producto
              , sum(compra.cantidad) as compra
                from detalle_compra AS compra
                          inner join producto AS pro on compra.id_producto = pro.id_producto
                group by pro.id_producto),
     ventas
     as (select pro.id_producto
              , sum(venta.cantidad) as venta
                from detall_venta AS venta
                          inner join producto AS pro on pro.id_producto = venta.id_producto
                group by pro.id_producto)
     Select coalesce(compras.id_producto, ventas.id_Producto) as idProducto
          , compras.compra
          , ventas.venta
          , isnull(compras.compra,0) - isnull(ventas.venta,0) as stock
            from compras
                      full join ventas on compras.id_producto = ventas.id_producto;
```

[Tablas de expresión común correlativas](https://javifer2.wordpress.com/2018/12/18/with-cte-tablas-de-expresion-comun-2-correlativos/)

[Diferentes combinaciones entre tablas](https://javifer2.wordpress.com/2019/09/16/combinaciones-entre-tablas-inner-left-right-full/)

Comment: señor Javi Fer2 Muchas gracias por  su respuesta , me  a servido de mucho , en el caso que solo tenga compras y no las ventas o viceversa como aria para que tambien me lo muestre en la tabla ? , de antemano muchas gracias maestro , bendiciones :)

Comment: De nada. La opción de full join te devuelve resultados, si tienes compras, y si tienes ventas. También si tienes ventas y no compras. O si tienes compras y no ventas. Prueba y verás el resultado.

Comment: si usted tiene razón, me sirvió , muchas gracias maestro , saludos desde Perú - Chimbote  :)